# prototyping tool that support hover

Tags: ux-designer, prototype

I'm, new to UX and I want to ask you as experts to help me. I need to create interactive prototype and I found many great options but not many support hover effects, and I believe it is important to have this effect in prototyping.

So can you suggest some tools that support hover effect.

Thank you :)

Comment: Depends on what kind of prototyping you're doing. Invision doesn't let you do many advanced interactions or effects, but it does support hover states. Its trial is free, so you can try it out.

Comment: can you recommend tool for interactive prototyping? thanks

Comment: [Asking for tool recommendation is off topic](https://ux.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2026/on-what-forum-do-i-ask-ux-tool-based-questions-if-not-here-on-ux-se/2027#2027)

Comment: This question can be answered objectively as true/false and is not solely opinion based. It’s a UX tool that supports hover interactions out of the box. Unless there’s a software recommendations SE just for UX tool discussions, this seems like the logical place to get that answer quickly.

Comment: Axure allows mocking up hover effects.

Comment: I’m not sure why this question is considered opinion-based. No one has asked for clarification as to what functionality the asker is referring to. It’s unambiguous and can be answered objectively as true or false. Even the mention of PowerPoint, which is not marketed or sold as a prototyping tool, references a detailed method for achieving the asker’s desired functionality. In sum: please lighten up.

Answer (score 4):

[Axure](https://www.axure.com/support/training/interactive-button-tutorial) models web interactions so you can make use of :hover and many other browser events in your prototypes.

It’s pretty intuitive, this inspector window shows the :onclick event but :hover is in the same menu:

[image: https://d2v8ggac1o0f6z.cloudfront.net/gsc/HGGQY3/18/32/18/183218e2a33644fb913738c1330f98ea/images/interactions/u17243.png]

Answer (score 0):

Here's a list of prototyping tools I know that support hover:

**Simple interaction**

- [Invision](https://www.invisionapp.com/blog/launch-new-hotspot-behaviors-hover-anchor-external-url/)
- [Marvel](https://help.marvelapp.com/hc/en-us/articles/115003261989-Add-a-hover-to-your-prototype-)

**Advanced interaction**

- [Atomic.io](https://help.atomic.io/prototyping/gestures)
- [Flinto](https://www.flinto.com/blog/enhanced-desktop-support)
- [Framer](https://framer.com/)
- [Origami Studio](https://origami.design/documentation/patches/builtin.layer.hover.html)
- [Principle](http://principleformac.com/docs.html#hover-inside)

As Luke Smith mentions, you may also try the complex prototyping tool Axure. Or you can go a whole different direction and use a presentation tool like PowerPoint for your prototype ([here](https://alesandrab.wordpress.com/2014/07/21/hover-over-events-in-powerpoint/)'s an article about its hover effects).

Comment: Does PowerPoint support hover?

Comment: @LukeSmith I don't have PowerPoint, so I can't check, but it seems like it does based on the article I linked to.

Answer (score 0):

Here is [a sample from Atomic.io that demonstrates a hover](https://app.atomic.io/d/c6fzUzyNKfoZ) (& click) effect:

https://app.atomic.io/d/c6fzUzyNKfoZ

You can copy this sample into your own account, and modify it for your own use.

Here is an article on [hover & other gestures](https://help.atomic.io/prototyping/gestures) in Atomic.

Answer (score 0):

[Framer](https://framer.com/) supports hover. However, the easiest method is sometimes building an html/css prototype to illustrate a hover state. [Codepen](http://codepen.io) is great for stuff like that.